# how to count distinct values in excel for a matrix form

Tags: excel, matrix, distinct, countif

I have looked if this has been asked, but could not find out exactly.

I' ve been trying to count distinct values.
I tried sumproduct,sum(1/countif) etc, so far I got nothing  but a div error or 0.

Basically, I' ve two columns: Campaign_no and customer_id.
what I need is count unique customers for each campaigns and count unique customers that appears in the campaigns at the same time, sort of matrix.

The table is as follows:

| Campaign_no | Cust_id |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 9 |
| C | 4 |
| C | 5 |
| C | 6 |
| C | 7 |

What I need is below:

| Campaigns | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| C | 0 | 2 | 4 |

As you see Campaign A has 2 unique customers, so A-A cell is 2.
Campaign A and B have one customer in common, so A-B cell is 1.

Campaign A and C have no common customer, this box got 0.
Campaign B and C has 4 unique customer on their own,
but they have two common customers, so B-C box has 2 ( if those customers were the same, it would have been 1) .

Is there way of calculating this without vba or PT? I'm using Excel 2017.
Much appreciated.

Comment: I do not think this possible with formula in anything but O365.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using helper cells.

[image: Sample Solution]

C2 is `=A2&B2`.  Copy it to C3:C12.

D2 is `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B2,D1:$D$1,0)),B2,"")`.  Copy it to D3:D12.

E2 is `=IF($D2="","",1-ISNA(MATCH(E$1&$D2,$C$2:$C$12,0)))`.  Copy it to E2:G12.

E15 is `=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$12,E2:E12,1)`. Copy it to F15:G15.

E16 is `=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$12,E2:E12,1)`. Copy it to F16:G16.

E17 is `=SUMIFS($G$2:$G$12,E2:E12,1)`. Copy it to F17:G17.

You may be able to get away without using the helper column C in Office 2017.  I only have Office 365, so I couldn't it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that you could try, but it assumes that the data is *sorted into contiguous blocks in alphabetical order of campaign* exactly as shown in the sample data:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12,F$1,$B$2:$B$12,INDEX($B$2:$B$12,MATCH($E2,$A$2:$A$12,0)):INDEX($B$2:$B$12,MATCH($E2,$A$2:$A$12,1)))>0)
/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12,$E2,$B$2:$B$12,INDEX($B$2:$B$12,MATCH($E2,$A$2:$A$12,0)):INDEX($B$2:$B$12,MATCH($E2,$A$2:$A$12,1))))
```

The idea is that you use countifs to check through each customer ID in campaign A (for example) to see if it's present in campaign B. But it's possible that a customer ID appears more than once in campaign A, so you still have to divide by the count of each customer number in campaign A to get the unique count.

[image]